# How to detect a new record event

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase

I have to do a usecase where, whenever a new record is created in a firebase database, a scheduled task created in AppEngine should automatically trigger a separate business logic. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?. Thank You.

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio on how to access Firebase from Google App Engine.

Comment: Thank you. Shall check that out.